# Update to .NET6, Serilog 2.12 and Sinks.ApplicationInsights 4.0.0

Tags: azure-application-insights, serilog

I have updated a worker service application to .NET6 from .NET Core 3.1, and also updated Serilog and the Application Insights sink to the latest versions.

I noticed that even though I this entry on the configuration, I don't see the application name on App Insights, it is always blank.  This used to work with the previous version

```
"WriteTo": [
  {
    "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
    "Args": {
      "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
      "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
      "InstrumentationKey": "<Key>"
    }
  }
],
"Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
"Properties": {
  "Application": "ApplicationName"
}
```

Any idea how I get this to work again?

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

Check the below steps to get the `ApplicationName` on `App Insights` for `.NET 6` Application.

Updated the `Serilog.AspNetCore` and `Sinks.ApplicationInsights` packages to the latest version.

- Add  `.Enrich.FromLogContext()` and
  .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", appname) in `Program.cs` file.

***My `appsettings.json` file :***

```cs
{
  "Logging": {
    "ApplicationInsights": {
      "LogLevel": {
        "Default": "Debug",
        "Microsoft": "Error"
      }
    },
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft.AspNetCore": "Warning"
    }
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*",
  "ApplicationInsights": {
    "ConnectionString": "InstrumentationKey=*****;IngestionEndpoint=https://****.in.applicationinsights.azure.com/;LiveEndpoint=https://****.livediagnostics.monitor.azure.com/"
  },
  "WriteTo": [
    {
      "Name": "ApplicationInsights",
      "Args": {
        "restrictedToMinimumLevel": "Information",
        "telemetryConverter": "Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters.TraceTelemetryConverter, Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights",
        "InstrumentationKey": "Copy the Instrumentation Key"
      }
    }
  ],
  "Enrich": [ "FromLogContext" ],
  "Properties": {
    "Application": "Serilog Application Insights"
  }
}
```

***My `Program.cs` file :***

```cs
using Serilog;
using Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights.TelemetryConverters;
using System.ComponentModel;
using static System.Net.Mime.MediaTypeNames;


var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

builder.Services.AddControllersWithViews();

var appname = builder.Configuration.GetSection("Properties").GetValue<string>("Application");

var AIConn = builder.Configuration.GetSection("ApplicationInsights").GetValue<string>("ConnectionString");

var log = new LoggerConfiguration()
    .Enrich.FromLogContext()
    .Enrich.WithProperty("ApplicationName", appname)
 .WriteTo.ApplicationInsights(AIConn, new TraceTelemetryConverter())
 .CreateLogger();

Log.Information("Log message from Program.cs file");
Log.Warning("Warning Message");
builder.Logging.AddSerilog(log);

var app = builder.Build();

if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseExceptionHandler("/Home/Error");
    app.UseHsts();
}

app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller=Home}/{action=Index}/{id?}");
app.Run();
```

***My `.csproj` file :***

```cs
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>net6.0</TargetFramework>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.AspNetCore" Version="6.1.0" />
    <PackageReference Include="Serilog.Sinks.ApplicationInsights" Version="4.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

In `Transaction search`, click on any of the trace.

[image]

It will be redirected to the `End-to-end transaction details`.

***OutPut in Application Insights :***

[image]

Comment: Thank you @Harshitha.  I create the logger this way var logger = new LoggerConfiguration().ReadFrom.Configuration(configuration).CreateLogger(); and just by having the Enrich and Properties in the appsettings.json file it used to work. Not sure why it stopped after the upgrade.  I did update all the Serilog libs to their latest versions.

Comment: @Fernando May be latest version need more settings in `appsettings.json` and change in configuration in `Program.cs` file. Iam able to get the traces with the above code.